# What is the origin of this medallion?

Tags: ancient-history, archaeology, canada, metallurgy

I want to get information on [what looks
like a medallion](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PHtwyidKKg4hIZc1mJMPK0cobY39A4Xv/view?usp=sharing) that my father found at a construction
site (at his home) in 1968 in Port Colborne, Ontario, Canada. It was found about 10 feet underground. It is about 4.5 CM in diameter. Thus far, we have heard the following from an Archaeology professor:
"Both of us thought it was modern but with an ancient near eastern motif.  We both thought the arrows were out of place."

[image: Front]

[image: Scale]
[image: Back]
[image: Edge 1]
[image: Edge 2]

Comment: @justCal I have uploaded new photos. Thanks!

Comment: Probably gazelles and date fruits (from a palm tree).

Comment: Maybe its a referrat to the ancient city of Ephesus (coins contained deer and date fruits), maybe it's some Christian thing.